# accented characters breaks json_encode() in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have an array which one of the keys contains some HTML code. I am json_encoding this array for returning. I have recently noticed that json_encode() returns 'null' if the html contains special characters (ie: A méh virága).

How can I get json_encode() not to return 'null' if special accented characters are available?

Comment: do you have correct encoding (UTF-8 preferably) set on your page as well as in the file that does the JSON encoding?

Comment: I tested this and there were no problem with html content, please provide us some code ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json_encode()` assumes that text is in UTF-8 encoding. If the input looks like malformed UTF-8, it returns `null`. The only way to get `json_encode()` to work is to give it input in UTF-8 (which you should probably be using anyway).

And, as Zathrus Writer says in a comment, the actual PHP source code itself should probably also be in UTF-8 encoding, to prevent subtle bugs.

Comment: So how does one give json_encode utf 8 input, when you have accented characters etc?

Comment: Accented characters can be in many encodings, but UTF-8 is the only sensible one for most purposes. How you get there, though, depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

My answer, wrapped the html string with utf8_encode().

Comment: Playing around with character encodings without understanding what's breaking and why can fix things, but it's a dangerous way to go about it.