# UTF8 in MySQL != UTF8 in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

So I was having an issue with `json_encode` returning null that I found the solution for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456762/accented-characters-breaks-json-encode-in-php), but I don't understand why it was an issue in the first place. The MySQL tables from which I was drawing the data are defined like

```
CREATE TABLE `super_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `values` text,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

so shouldn't `values` and `name` be utf8 encoded already when I pull them out in PHP? A simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM super_table";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
$data = (object) $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
    $data->$key = utf8_encode($val);
}
$result = array('success'=>$success, 'data'=>$data);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Why does not doing the extra `utf8_encode` step sometimes yield a null result when I try to `json_encode` it?

Comment: The `utf8` charset in mysql is a special UTF-8 charset with only 3 bytes instead of 4. `utf8mb4` is the true UTF-8 charset in mysql with 4 bytes.

Comment: You should also check if the MySQLi connection in PHP is using UTF-8 for transmission between these two parties. http://php.net/mysqli_set_charset

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois How does one check that?

Comment: http://php.net/mysqli_character_set_name

Comment: Also make sure your php file is in utf8 and that it outputs the data in utf8 (see the link that @Robert gives)

Comment: If you need to use `utf8_encode()`, there is something wrong elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Indeed, MySQL's `utf8` is not universally understood UTF-8. Even though this is not your issue here... MySQL's `utf8` is a subset of actual UTF-8 only covering the BMP and not supporting 4-byte characters. But this just means that high characters will get discarded; otherwise it's still UTF-8 compatible.
2. Your actual issue is that MySQL is just *storing* the data in `utf8`, but that says nothing about how you will receive the data in your database client. MySQL converts text on the fly from the stored encoding **to the connection encoding** (and vice versa). When connecting to the database in your PHP code, you can choose which encoding you prefer to receive your data in. [Use `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8')`](http://php.net/mysqli_set_charset) to retrieve your data in UTF-8.